# What's the approach of getting the web project into Android phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a working web application. How would I refer to the index.html to this app's index.html?

```
super.loadUrl(“file:///android_asset/www/index.html”);
```

My web app already have the index.html. Do I just refer to that URL? Say my app is at:

```
www.myapp.com
```

Do I just type that address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quickly get it up and running put your index.html and any other html/images/css/javascript into zip file and upload to the PhoneGap build site. There's more to it that that but for a simple static app that will work.

Comment: Its not a simple static app.